# Request to cancel bounty

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty

I inadvertently started on the question [Convert string to image with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299230/convert-string-to-image-with-php/46299745?noredirect=1#comment79565762_46299745) a bounty, which is unnecessary, as I already added the solution. Is it possible to "undo" this?

Comment: Only moderators can end bounties prematurely. I'm not sure if they also can refund the rep or if that needs SE staff.

Comment: How can I reach a moderator then?

Comment: When a moderator removes an active bounty, it refunds the reputation. Normally, you request this sort of thing with a moderator flag, but…since we're here…I've gone ahead and refunded that bounty. Everyone gets one free mistake. :-)